# What is the range of the angle returned by minAreaRect?

Tags: python, opencv

Checking the documentation and the posts related to cv2.minAreaRect, I have noticed that the returned angle value should be within the range [-90, 0). When I try to run minAreaRect for the following vertices, it returns the positive value:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

vertices = np.array([[     67.264,       357.4],
       [     484.47,      364.68],
       [     473.14,      1013.5],
       [     55.938,      1006.2]])
test = cv2.minAreaRect(np.array(vertices)) # returns ((270.2044677734375, 685.4646606445312), (417.27044677734375, 648.945068359375), 1.0000191926956177)
```

Has there been anything changed? what is the actual range of the return value?

Comment: Things have definitely changed, at least twice in history of 4.x -- I think I've seen a change between 4.4 and 4.5 (the width/height are swapped, and angle became positive by adding 90 -- just different representation of the same rectangle). Another change appears to be between 4.2 and 4.3 (in cases with multiple solutions, a different one may be picked, but that's not the case with your params). | BTW, you [mcve] throws an exception -- replace the first `np.array` with `np.float32`, and drop the second one which is redundant.

Comment: Personally, I'd at least expect [-90,90], but given that it's not specified in the docs (and `RotatedRect` -- the return type -- doesn't put any limits on it), the safest bet is to handle all four quadrants. (IIRC similar situation was with `fitEllipse`, and back then i just wrote it to handle any value of angle, and normalized it to a range that was convenient for me).

Comment: See https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/

Answer (score 1):

It's not formally defined. Here's what one of the OpenCV contributors has said about it:

> angle range is unspecified (neither before nor after). Also algorithm's implementation doesn't define even width/height relations (can be swapped with 90 degree angle adjustment). For example, if we want to force `width >= height`, then angle range's size should be 180 degrees.
>
> anything that is stated in documentation should have corresponding implementation and must be validated by tests.

In other words, the official docs don't say anything about the angle range, to give freedom for future changes in minAreaRect.

In the specific case you're looking at, I believe this was caused by a [change to fix a bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/19068). I don't entirely follow why changing the convexHull step to use CCW instead of CW coordinates causes an angle change, but it seems to be why it changed. [More information](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19472).